# Python Pyqt5: How to reference object

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Ive used qt-designer to make a ui and I've setup the code to open it but I wand to reference the buttons (and all others) as object so for example if I wanted to ask a multiple choice question the question would appear in a Text Browser and the buttons (1-6) would be enabled and when the button is pressed the choose would be made and the program would continue. Btw the code here is just the code for the ui the rest of it is already done but its test based and I wanted to add a gui but I didn't know how so I'm useing PyQt5.

```
from tkinter.tix import Form

# import MyGUI as MyGUI
import self as self
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


# Form, Window = uic.loadUiType("Stock-Watchlist-Logger.ui")

class MyGUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGUI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("Stock-Watchlist-Logger.ui", self)
        self.show()

        self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.clicked1)
        print(self)
        # button1 = self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        # button2 =\
        self.Button2.clicked.connect(self.clicked2)
        # button3 =\
        self.Button3.clicked.connect(self.clicked3)
        # button4 =\
        self.Button4.clicked.connect(self.clicked4)
        # button5 = \
        self.Button5.clicked.connect(self.clicked5)
        # button6 =\
        self.Button6.clicked.connect(self.clicked6)
        self.YesButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedyes)
        self.NoButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedno)



    button1 = False
    button2 = False
    button3 = False
    button4 = False
    button5 = False
    button6 = False
    yesbutton = False
    nobutton = False

    def clicked1(self):
        MyGUI.button1 = True
        print(MyGUI.button1)
        # return button1
    def clicked2(self):
        button2 = True
        return button2
    def clicked3(self):
        button3 = True
        return button3
    def clicked4(self):
        button4 = True
        return button4
    def clicked5(self):
        button5 = True
        return button5
    def clicked6(self):
        button6 = True
        return button6
    def clickedyes(self):
        yesbutton = True
        return yesbutton
    def clickedno(self):
        nobutton = True
        return nobutton
    print(button1)

# print(MyGUI.clicked1)
# num = MyGUI.clicked1()
# print(num)
# if num == 1:
#     button1 = True
# elif num == 2:
#     button2 = True
# elif num == 3:
#     button3 = True
# elif num == 4:
#     button4 = True
# elif num == 5:
#     button5 = True
# elif num == 6:
#     button6 = True
# else: print("Error: not an option1.1")


# variables
# if
# Button1 =
# Functions

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MyGUI()
    # form = Form()
    # form.setupUi(window)

    # window.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 300)
    # window.setWindowTitle("Stock Watchlist & Logger")
    #
    # # label = QLabel(window)
    # # label.setText("Press button for a suprise!")
    # #
    # # label.setText("Hoi Kataki")
    # # label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 16))
    # # label.move(50, 100)
    #
    # layout = QVBoxLayout()
    # label = QLabel("Press button for a suprise!")
    # textbox = QTextEdit()
    #
    # label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 16))
    # label.move(50, 100)
    # button = QPushButton("Press me for a suprise!")
    # button.clicked.connect(lambda: on_clicked(textbox.toPlainText()))
    # layout.addWidget(label)
    # layout.addWidget(textbox)
    # layout.addWidget(button)
    #
    # window.setLayout(layout)


    window.show()
    app.exec_()




def on_clicked(msg):
    print("Button Clicked!!!")
    message = QMessageBox()
    message.setText(msg)
    message.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # # num = MyGUI.clicked1(MyGUI)
    # while MyGUI.button1 != True:

    main()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you are having?  There are numerous problems with your code, but I don't exactly know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have buttons in a gun and I want to be able to use them like this: 
1. Display question
2. Wait for one of the buttons to be pressed
3. when a button is pressed see which one it was and work some code 

I have existing code, I'm just trying to upgrade it with GUI